# tinyMCE SetContent() causes undo step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-3

After I SetContent() on the tinyMCE plugin (Version 3), in the event that a user changes something small like the formatting of a piece of that text block for example, the next undo step will clear the entire text block instead of just clearing the formatting change.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Is there a call I can make after the SetContent() to make sure the next undo step only includes the formatting change and not the entire block of text?

I've attempted calling UndoManager.clear() after the set but that didn't seem to change the behavior.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use

tinyMCE.getInstanceById("editorTexto").setContent(obj.texto);
     tinyMCE.getInstanceById("editorTexto").undoManager.clear();

It works in version 3.5.4

Comment: I forgot I posted this question but yes, that is the solution I ended up going with. Will mark as answer for future reference.